# TestCafe: Failed to complete a request to url

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

### Summary

We have smoke tests that run shortly after deployment on our web application. Sometimes it takes the login page takes a while for its first load.

### Error

```
- Error in Role initializer -
Failed to complete a request to "https://myurl.com/account/login/" within the
timeout period. The problem may be related to local machine's network or firewall settings, server outage, or network problems that make the server inaccessible.
```

### Possible Solutions

I'm hoping that adding a `setPageTimeout` in my Roles will solve this issue, however, I can't confirm until Tuesday.

Can anyone confirm if `setPageTimeout` is the way to go? If not, is there a solution available?

### Example Solution

```js
import { Role } from 'testcafe';
import { config, pageWait } './config/config';
import { loginPage } from '../pages'

const defaultPageTimeout = 5000;

export const orgAdminRole: Role = Role(config.baseUrl, async t => {
    await t
        .setPageLoadTimeout(pageWait.extraLongPoll)
        .typeText(loginPage.userNameInput, config.orgAdminUser)
        .typeText(loginPage.passwordInput, config.orgAdminPass)
        .click(loginPage.loginButton)
        .setPageLoadTimeout(defaultPageTimeout);
}, { preserveUrl: true });

export const userRole: Role = Role(config.baseUrl, async t => {
    await t
        .setPageLoadTimeout(pageWait.extraLongPoll)
        .typeText(loginPage.userNameInput, config.user)
        .typeText(loginPage.passwordInput, config.userPass)
        .click(loginPage.loginButton)
        .setPageLoadTimeout(defaultPageTimeout);
}, { preserveUrl: true });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPD: Use the following API to configure your timeouts:**

1. [`--page-load-timeout-ms`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--page-load-timeout-ms)
2. [`--ajax-request-timeout-ms`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--ajax-request-timeout-ms)
3. [`--page-request-timeout-ms`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--page-request-timeout-ms)
4. [Test.timeouts Method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403062/reference/test-api/test/timeouts)

**Old answer:**
The reason of this issue is the request timeouts. So, using [setPageLoadTimeout](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/setpageloadtimeout.html) is not a solution in your test case.

As a workaround, I suggest you change the request timeouts:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

// Import DestinationRequest from the testcafe-hammerhead module. Please, specify your own environment path.
import { DestinationRequest } from '../../../../../../node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/destination-request';

fixture `Fixture`
  .page `https://example.com`;

test('test', async t => {
  // Set timeouts
  DestinationRequest.XHR_TIMEOUT = 10 * 60 * 1000; // XHR requests timeout
  DestinationRequest.TIMEOUT     = 10 * 60 * 1000; // other requests timeout

  // Actions and assertions

  // Restore default timeouts
  DestinationRequest.XHR_TIMEOUT = 2 * 60 * 1000;
  DestinationRequest.TIMEOUT     = 25 * 1000;
});
```

We will consider the implementation of public options to set the timeouts in the context of the following issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2940.

Comment: Thanks! Trying this out now. I'll see how things run over the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the previous answer I think TestCafe have changed `DestinationRequest` exporting mode. So I'm using as `import * as DestinationRequest ...`.